# Read both String and int from text file with BufferedReader into HashSet Java

Tags: java, string, int, bufferedreader

The text file look like this:

name1

1

name2

2

The method prints:

[name: name1 shirt number: 1]

This is how I want it to print:

[name: name1 shirt number: 1, name: name2 shirt number: 2, and so on]

It only prints the first element. Feels like I tried everything but I can't get it to work. Someone got a possible solution?

```
public void loadPlayerDatabase(String fileName) throws IOException {

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

        String currentLine;
        int counter = 0;
        String name = null;

        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                name = currentLine;
                counter++;

            } else {
                Player player = new Player();
                player.setName(name);
                players.add(player);
                player.setNumber(number);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        counter++;
    } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
        System.out.println("That didn't work!" + n.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(players);
}
```

Comment: Because you add only one name. Try to remove your condition if(counter %2).

Comment: where is `players` defined?

Comment: private final Set<Player> players = new HashSet<>();
players is my HashSet. I have it in the top of class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://gist.github.com/vedharish/bbf07dc3a90847c5c19b) should work.

The readLine() function continues on to the next line in the input and hence you don't need to skip lines.

Comment: This kind of worked. 
I added int counter = 0;
otherwise the variable counter is never used.
Also it warns String name = null; That the assigned value is never used.

Comment: This works. Thanks for the help!

Now back to fixing other parts of the code :)